# Dynamically updating the passed parameter in the vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-vue

I have component:

```
<g :title="computeString"></g>
```

(standart element)

I use computed property to update it

```
 computeString:{
     get: function () {
       console.log(this.cage.hitch);
       return this.cage.hitch
     },
     set: function(newValue) {
       return newValue;
     }
   },
```

But when I update the calculated field, the title is not updated.

How to dynamically update?

Try 2:

```
computeString:{
        get: function () {
          console.log(this.cage.hitch);
         return this.cage.hitch
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
      this.cage.hitch = newValue;
       }
    },
```

Not work.

Comment: What is `<g>`? If you remove the computed out of the equation, is `<g title="test">` rendering the way you want? Also, what you've shown has no obvious errors, which means the bug is caused by something you're not showing. Which makes your question, technically: a) unanswerable; b) off-topic Consider adding a *runnable* [mcve].

Comment: I agree with @tao suggestions, and not sure why you are declaring a 'get' and 'set' instead of just defining 
computeString() {
   return this.cage.hitch
}

Comment: @Tim: [computed setter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

Comment: @tao I have seen that documentation, but in this case he is just setting this.cage.hitch, which he should be able to do directly without a specific setter, assuming 'cage' is a defined in his 'data'.  Not shown in his code snippets.